# Match island block inside text with pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, pyparsing

I want to match well-formed blocks inside a plain text document. The blocks can contain plain text or other nested blocks.

Let's say that a block is defined as starting with "begin" keyword and ending with "end" keyword. An example string to parse can be something like:

```
bla
bla bla
begin
   bla
   begin
     bla bla
   end
   bla
end
bla bla bla
```

I tried this

```
import pyparsing as pp

grammar = pp.Forward()
begin = pp.Keyword('begin')
end = pp.Keyword('end')
block = begin + pp.Group(grammar) + end
plain_txt = pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas))
grammar << pp.ZeroOrMore(block | plain_txt)
```

but it doesn't match blocks! What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `ZeroOrMore` in `plain_txt` does not know not to consume 'begin' or 'end' keywords. Try changing plain_text to `ZeroOrMore(~begin + ~end + pp.Word(pp.alphas))`.

Comment: Thanks! Suppose that there are many types of blocks with a variety of syntaxes. Is there any solution other than tilde-negate all keywords?

Comment: Not really - but you can create a single expression that represents any keyword like `keyword = begin | end | start | finish | switch | case; plain_txt = pp.ZeroOrMore(~keyword + pp.Word(pp.alphas))` You may find such a keyword expression useful elsewhere as well, such as `identifier = ~keyword + pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums+'_')`

Comment: Yes that is it! Sorry I'm new to pyparsing...